# Matlab fmincon for bundle adjustment in 3D reconstruction

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, mathematical-optimization

I have a hard time using fmincon in matlab for bundle adjustment in 3D computer vision applications, any sample for 3D reconstruction?

Comment: What have you tried? How have you attempted to set up the call to `fmincon`?

Comment: Any error messages? In what way are you having a hard time?

Comment: I do not know how to use it, i do not get any error, i just dont get any better result compared to linear attempt. I need samples

Comment: Your comment doesn't make any sense. How can you "not know how to use it" while also being able to compare its results to something else?

Comment: What do you mean linear attempt? Also, Matlab is highly inefficient for 3D bundle adjustment. I'd recommend a standalone SFM package like Bundler [http://phototour.cs.washington.edu/bundler/]